# Groupchat file transfer like Skype in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, xmpp, file-transfer, groupchat

I am developing Windows chat application in C#.net using XMPP of agsXMPP library,for which I need to transfer files to group which could be downloaded by group members simultaneously, like Skype.

In XMPP there is outbound data transfer for this, but it uses URL, because of which file first needs to be uploaded, than can only be  downloaded by others. Please can anyone help me regarding how to implement peer to peer in group chat file transfer like Skype?

Comment: On Skype, if I locally delete a shared file, the file remains available for download to the other user. This makes me think they upload the file somewhere and then make it available. Am I understanding the questions wrong?

Comment: thank you,but it is not possible,i have already analysed it,once a sender deletes a sent file before others have downloaded file,than file will be unavailable.